# Modal content override by data-remote in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a remote content inside a `modal` using Twitter Bootstrap with this code:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb text-right">
    <li><a data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="/app_dev.php/resetting/request" href="#">Forgot password?</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal" data-remote="/app_dev.php/registro" href="#">Register</a></li>
</ol>

<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Alert</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on any link that trigger modal, like this image:

[image]

But then, when content is loaded, I lost the modal setup and the remote content replaces the complete modal layout, like this image:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

**Look in code generated by remote call**

I take a closer look to the modal after it loads and just the `<div class="modal-header">...</div>` dissapear and I don't know the cause. This is the code for the modal after it loads the remote content:

```
<div aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal" class="modal fade in" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="fos_user_resetting_request" class="fos_user_resetting_request form_registro" method="POST" action="/app_dev.php/resetting/send-email">
                <h2>Solicitar nueva contraseña</h2>
                <div>
                            <label for="username">Nombre de usuario:</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" name="username" id="username">
                    <input type="submit" value="Restablecer contraseña" id="reset_btn">
                </div>
            </form>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#fos_user_resetting_request").submit(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            cache: false,
                            url: "/resetting/send-email",
                            data: $(this).serializeArray(),
                            success: function(data) {
                                $.fancybox(data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Need codes to determine.

Comment: It seems that your modal's innerhtml is being overwritten. Can you post all of your relevant HTML / JavaScript?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I don't understand what you mean, can you explain?

Comment: @LindyHop this is the only relevant code and no Javascript is present, modal is triggered trough `data-*` parameters, which code you need?

Comment: you need to put content on $('.modal-body').html('PUT YOUR CONTENT OR RESPONSE');

Comment: @ashish.negi that make sense but then why the have `data-remote`? I shoun't need any code to insert the data in `.modal-body` :( as you suggest I'll need to make `$.get` call and get the content to set as HTML in the `.modal-body`

Comment: @ReynierPM - At the time I wrote my comment there isn't any JavaScript code included in your question.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 and there is not Javascript on the main code since trigger is handled trough `data-*` params on `<a>` element. That Javascript you see comes from the remote content loaded

Comment: The `remote` option of modals is being deprecated (see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034 ), so you'd be best off avoiding it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default it set the content on "modal-content" class. you can use ajax call to set content on "model-body" class or you can return following code in your remote function, then it will automatically set your model box.

```
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Alert</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               -- YOUR FORM ITEMS --
            </div>
```